# SQL Server stored procedure inserting wrong value into bit column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server stored procedure as follows

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AccessHistoryUpdate] 
    (@empPk int,
     @doorPk int)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ISNULL(@empPk, 0);
    SELECT ISNULL(@doorPk, 0);

    DECLARE @employeeRanking int;
    DECLARE @doorRanking int;

    SELECT
        SUM(e.SecurityDeviceId) AS emp
    FROM
        EmployeeSecurityDevice e
    WHERE
        e.EmployeeId = @empPk;

    SELECT
        SUM(d.SecurityDecivceId) AS door
    FROM
        DoorSecurityDevice d
    WHERE
        d.DoorId = @doorPk;
        
    IF (@employeeRanking >= @doorRanking)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO AccessHistory (AttemptDate, DoorId, EmployeeId, Result)
        VALUES(GETDATE(), @doorPk, @empPk, 1);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO AccessHistory (AttemptDate, DoorId, EmployeeId, Result)
        VALUES (GETDATE(), @doorPk, @empPk, 0);
    END
END
```

The result column is a bit column and I wrote if `employeeRanking` is greater than door ranking, it should return 1. For some reason it's returning 0 (behaving the reverse of what I would have expected)

Can someone point me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If you really write code like that (all in one line), it is not surprising that you have errors.

Comment: sorry the as begin select got put together

Comment: We can't run that SQL, so we can replicate the problem. Certainly, however, if `@employeeRanking` has a value greater to or equal to `@doorRanking` then `1` ***will*** be inserted, not `0`. If you have other thigns at work (such as triggers) that might change that, but as it stands, that's the logic you have. Take the time to give us a [mre], so we can actually understand the real problem.

Comment: Neither employeeRanking or doorRanking variables are assigned, so obviously the If comparison will be always false.

Comment: This smells like a big [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In particular, the summing of an ID column makes little logical sense. My guess is your data model is not well formed and not well defined - resulting in a struggle to write code.

Comment: Thanks to this comment, today I learned about the [Einstellung effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstellung_effect)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the assignment of the variables, this should do:

```
    select 
        @employeeRanking = sum (e.SecurityDeviceId)
    from 
        EmployeeSecurityDevice e
    where 
        e.EmployeeId = @empPk;

    select 
        @doorRanking = sum(d.SecurityDecivceId)
    from 
        DoorSecurityDevice d
    where 
        d.DoorId = @doorPk;
```

Comment: It didn't help to assign the variables.I still got the exact reverse of what I would have expected,and when I switched the insert statements(to put 0 in the result of the 1st and 1 in the 2nd) I got the result I wanted.But I don't understand that logic

Comment: Can we see some sample data from the tables EmployeeSecurityDevice and DoorSecurityDevice ?